# External promises never finish in unit tests with ngMock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-mock

I'm trying to unit test the resolution/rejection of external promises.

The problem is that those promises are never finished when `ngMock` module is injected - which is mandatory, as I'm triggering HTTP requests and timeouts.

Take for example [angular-pouchdb](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb), which is a dependency of my project. As of v2.0.0, because [PouchDB promises are used](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/issues/24), the tests no longer finish *when ngMock is injected*.

Example code, adapted from [angular-pouchdb tests](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/blob/7d5d616b03efb54cc22ddc43fbde2aa9c69de782/test/api.js):

```
var scope;
beforeEach(function() {
  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngMock', 'pouchdb']);
  var pouchDB = $injector.get('pouchDB');
  scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
  db = pouchDB('db');
});

it('should wrap destroy', function(done) {
  db.destroy()
    .then(shouldBeOK)
    .catch(shouldNotBeCalled)
    .finally(done);

  // No matter what's used ($apply, $applySync, $timeout.flush, etc) -- the tests will never finish.
  scope.$apply();
});
```

The log for the above test is the following:

```
C:\Users\Gustavo\Projetos\main\angular-pouchdb (master)
λ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket s1A7jIzmtcOxkGCtzYke with id 42899233
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Angular-aware PouchDB public API should wrap destroy FAILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

So, my question boils down to: **is there something I'm missing from unit testing Angular? Or is it an internal bug in ngMock?**

<sub>[This issue has been created in the angular-pouchdb repository as well](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/issues/57).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Edit 8/25: So we have actually solved this issue but I am still looking into what caused it.  I will have a more updated write up in a few days.

Alright after hitting at this problem in my spare time for a number of days I have narrowed this down to some sort of exception failure in a 3rd party promise from pouchDB where it hits a 10 second timeout and doesn't throw a clean error back.  I am able to get this by updating my

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
```

If I got back through and tweak a custom build and put some logging in to pouchDB I can confirm that the promise is not getting returned correctly in there,  I have been able to replicate this in 3.6 and 4.0 pouchDB.  From my wrapped console logs around the call nothing ever comes out of the wrapped call. Around test 3 I get uncaught 409 errors so there is clearly something not being handled correctly in pouchDB.

[image: Error Logs]

Here is an example without ngMock turned on so you can see how far it gets without it.

[image: Without ngMock]

Comment: `Error: No deferred tasks to be flushed` -- additionally, I can reproduce the same problem using Mocha.

Comment: Maybe for your testing purposes that you just need to verify nothing neds to be called like $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()

Comment: Also are you testing this in Chrome or PhantomJS because it may matter.

Comment: I was previously using Phantom, but Chrome has the same results.

Comment: can you post your package.json so I can replicate this.

Comment: The problem is reproducible in https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb

Comment: I can't even get a build to go through after cloning it, blows up an error for me.  My guess something in pouchdb is failing,  https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/issues/60  no way I can give much insight if I can't get it to build locally.

Comment: It looks like github is having some issues right now can't pull some things down and getting some errors from the repo as well, sigh.

Comment: PouchDB only uses third-party promises (a library called "lie") if the browser doesn't support Promises (e.g. PhantomJS, but not Chrome).. If you want to inject your own promises, you can override `window.Promise` and PouchDB will use that. Maybe Angular is overriding `window.Promise` somewhere?

Comment: Ah never mind, seems it was a bug in angular-pouchdb? Looks fixed now: https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/issues/60#issuecomment-132235422

Comment: This was for a separate issue, I use windows and build problems were frustrating me, I eventually just overrode leveldown to test pouchdb to try to isolate the issue.  This was more of I rather have the build scripts be OS agnostic.

Comment: Like I said the best I could come up with is that ngMock is overriding the promises I also see that pouchdb uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery to test instead of ngMock there could be just a incompatibility that is just specific to pouchDB but either way the issue isn't with angular-pouchdb.

Comment: Even though you still didn't solved the issue, your engagement into solving it was worth the bounty ;)

Answer (score -1):

I do not think it's ngMock issue, but I think it's because PhantomJS is not ready to support PouchDB yet.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10992

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/c55db55d7edbf0821538e027399536c260af5876/docs/adapters.md

Comment: [Build using angular-pouchdb v1.0.2 with callbacks](https://travis-ci.org/Syonet/model/builds/76355181)

Comment: If you read the comment from my answer I had asked gustavohenke already and he was able to replicate the problem is chrome as well.  I have confirmed this issue is not browser specific as well.